# Why does it say invalid expression?

Tags: c#

Why does this not work?

```
private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (plusButtonClicked == true)
    {
        total2 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
    else if (minusButtonClicked == true);
    {
        total2 = total1 - double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
    else if (multiplyButtonClicked == true);
    {
        total2 = total1 * double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        total2 = total1 / double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
```

It works until the second "else if" it says invalid expression else

Comment: Unrelated, but as a matter of style, consider avoiding `if (boolean == true)`. Instead, write `if (boolean)`.

Comment: This is a useless snippet to debug the problem. What are the types of `txtDisplay`, `total*` etc ... Please elaborate .. what exactly is the error, how are you debugging the code?

Answer (score 5):

Because you put a semicolon after the first else-if line.

```
private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (plusButtonClicked == true)
    {
        total2 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
    else if (minusButtonClicked == true);  // <<== There should not be a semicolon here
    {
        total2 = total1 - double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
    else if (multiplyButtonClicked == true); // <<== or here
    {
        total2 = total1 * double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        total2 = total1 / double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove semi-colons after the else if's

```
private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (plusButtonClicked == true)
    {
        total2 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
        else if (minusButtonClicked == true)
    {
        total2 = total1 - double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
        else if (multiplyButtonClicked == true)
    {
        total2 = total1 * double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
        else
    {
        total2 = total1 / double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

remove semicolon after else-if

```
 else if (minusButtonClicked == true);  //remove semicolon
```

also **no need** to use `==true` in `(minusButtonClicked == true)`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
            if (plusButtonClicked == true) 
            { 
                total2 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text); 
            }
            else if (minusButtonClicked == true) 
            { 
                total2 = total1 - double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text); 
            }
            else if (multiplyButtonClicked == true)
            { 
                total2 = total1 * double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text); 
            } 
            else
            { 
                total2 = total1 / double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
            }
        }
```

Comment: thankyouthankyouthankyouthankyouthankyouthankyou!!!! that was really nice of yall

Comment: private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            total1 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
            txtDisplay.Clear();

            plusButtonClicked = true;
            minusButtonClicked = false;
            divideButtonClicked = false;
            multiplyButtonClicked = false;

Comment: i need to find why total1 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text); is "input string in the wrong format

Answer (score 0):

Meaning of semicolon after if-else menace you just stop the condition.

Remove `;`

and add:

```
private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (plusButtonClicked == true)
    {
        total2 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
        else if (minusButtonClicked == true)
    {
        total2 = total1 - double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
        else if (multiplyButtonClicked == true)
    {
        total2 = total1 * double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
        else
    {
        total2 = total1 / double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    }
  }
```